# How the representation acting on a lie algebra element, $\rho(g)$, turns to a matrix acting on a vector $v$ of a vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Suppose we have the lie group $G$. Its Lie algebra is $\mathfrak{g}$. A representation $\rho$ is given by: $\rho: \mathfrak{g}\to\mathrm{End}(V)$.

For the case of the lie group $SU(2)$, its Lie algebra is $\mathfrak{su}(2)$. A representation $\rho$ is given by:

$$\rho: \mathfrak{su}(2)\to\mathrm{End}(\mathbb{C}^{2}) \tag{1}$$

Therefore, we have conceptually,

\begin{alignat*}{2}
  \rho:\mathfrak{su}(2)&\longrightarrow& \mathrm{End}(\mathbb{C}^{2}) \\
  g&\longmapsto& \rho(g):\mathbb{C}^{2} &\longrightarrow\mathbb{C}^{2}\\
  &&v&\longmapsto\rho(g)v
\end{alignat*}

I know that the most basic notion of representation theory  is the very map $\rho$. But I did't grasp yet how and when the object $\rho(g)$ becomes a matrix! I mean, in the end we want to implement and render the vague notion of a element of $SU(2)$ acting on some vector space, also elements of the algebra $\mathfrak{su}(2)$ acting on a vector space; so the technology of representations are what we looking for simply because the have $\rho(g) \equiv T$ acting (linearly) on $v$, i.e., $Tv = w$. But again,

> **How and when the object $\rho(g)$ turns to a matrix acting on $v$?**

*Please, I do understand that a linear transformation, specially in finite-dimension vector space theory, have matrix counterparts. But, I don't understand if $\rho(g)$ is already a matrix (since we can have groups of matrices) or you need to construct a matrix representation for it. And I don't know if the usage of the word "representation" in this last sentence have double meaning.*

Comment: Not taking anything away from the answer, but the answer to the question is: Just like *any* endomorphism $f\in End_K(V)$ turns into a matrix $A\in M_{n\times n}(K)$ (for any $n$-dimensional $K$-vector space $V$): Via a choice of basis, i.e. a choice of isomorphism $V \simeq K^n$, like taught in any Linear Algebra class.

Answer (score 1):

In words, a Lie algebra representation of $\mathfrak{g}$ on a vector space $V$ associates to each $X\in \mathfrak{g}$ a linear operator $\rho(g)\in \mathrm{End}(V)$ as you stated above (in a structure preserving manner). These linear operators do not come with canonical matrix representations; this depends on a choice of basis.

Since you are making your representation on $\Bbb{C}^2 = V$, there is already a canonical basis lying around; namely $\{(1,0),(0,1)\}$. So, using this you can identify $\mathrm{End}(\Bbb{C}^2) \cong M_{2}(\Bbb{C})$ if you so choose.

Sidenote: You mention a slight ambiguity in the use of the word "representation." I always imagined that the source of the terminology "representation" of (e.g.) a group $G$ was to *represent* its elements as matrices acting on some finite dimensional vector space $k^n$. This might explain the terminology of a "representation" of a group (or algebra) being a homomorphism into a space of linear endomorphisms of $V$; after choosing a basis of $V$, this is a "representation" in the other sense.

Comment: Thanks. How can I see Pauli matrices appearing in this scheme?

Comment: The Pauli matrices are a basis for $\mathfrak{su}(2)$, which it is worth noting is defined as a matrix Lie algebra. As such, it comes with a natural representation $\mathfrak{su}(2) \to \mathrm{End}(\Bbb{C}^2)$ just by sending $X\in \mathfrak{su}(2)$ to the associated linear transformation on $\Bbb{C}^2$ which it defines. The Pauli matrices are a choice of basis for $\mathfrak{su}(2)$ and as such any representation of $\mathfrak{su}(2)$ is determined by how these 3 matrices act.

Comment: Thanks again. And how the spatial and algebra indexes appears (in the case of special relativity will be the gamma matrices and time will appear as well)? Like, the Pauli Matrices are $\sigma_{i}$, but $i$ are the 3D indexes. In fact, the whole symbolic notation is: $\sigma_{ib}^{a}$ where $a,b$ are the indexes associated with the lie algebra theory.  My first guess would be: $\rho(g_{i}) \equiv \sigma_{i}$ but I don't know since $i$ is for space not for the algebra.